How to best convert values into another values in TS?
Let's say I have a list of countries that are country coded and I want to display a proper word for each code that I receive as props for my component.
interface MyComponentProps {
  countryCode: 'en' | 'de' | 'fr';
}

const MyComponent: FC<MyComponentProps> = ({countryCode}) => (
  <p>{countryCode}</p>
)

So in the component above I'd like to display for example English when I get 'en' as props, German for de... you get the idea. What is the best way convert these values into other values according to some map like 'en' = 'English', 'de' = 'German' etc?

Probably I don't get the answer. But you just need to build a map like const countries = {"en": "english, "de": "German}, you don't even need a function.

I personally call it "dictionary"
const countriesDictionary = {
  'eua': 'United States',
  'fr': 'France',
  'de': 'Germany',
};

interface MyComponentProps {
  countryCode: keyof typeof countriesDictionary, // allow just valid keys in countriesDictionary
}

const MyComponent: FC<MyComponentProps> = ({countryCode}) => {
  console.log(countriesDictionary['eua']) // United States

  return (<p>{countriesDictionary[countryCode]}</p>)
}


How is this different from my answer?

I didn't saw it before posting mine, however that code will not cause any compiler warn as the countryCode depends on the dictionary, so its easier to add new countries to it

That's what the satisfies clause is for: my code will fail to compile if there's a missing country code in the dictionary.

Yeah, but in order to add new countries you'll need to change two places: the union type of countryCode and the dictionary.  countryCode dependency on the dictionary allows you to make changes to the dictionary only, everything will be in sync. Another thing is that a long list of countries would be harder to maintain and read with union types

True. It really depends on whether the OP wants the dictionary to be the source of truth or the string literal union type as the source of truth.

Just use an object literal:
import React from 'react'

interface MyComponentProps {
  countryCode: 'en' | 'de' | 'fr';
}

const map = {
    en: 'English',
    de: 'German',
    fr: 'French',
} satisfies Record<MyComponentProps['countryCode'], string>

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({countryCode}) => (
  <p>{map[countryCode]}</p>
)

Playground
Note that the satisfies clause will cause the compiler to warn you if you forget a key in the map. If you don't want that completeness checking you can delete that bit.
